# How to resize div element by selecting one side in angular2

Tags: html, angular

Page has two div elements in columns and my requirement is to resize the left column by selecting one side (right edge).

Below is my HTML code

```
<div id="leftSide" class="left-panel" >
    <div class="left-top-panel">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rightSide" class="right-panel" >
</div>
```

I know there is css resize property. This is not helping me because using this element can be resized by selecting a corner.

I want to achieve this in my angular2 components. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that would be solved by a library or similar, not by Angular.  Angular provides a framework that might allow you to hook into that sort of logic, but I would recommend using CSS/Component libraries to provide you with that functionality.